# SlingServletFilter annotation doesn't generate properties

Tags: osgi, aem, sling

I am trying to annotate a sling filter in AEM 6.4 SP2 with the new

```
@SlingServletFilter(scope=SlingServletFilterScope.REQUEST)
```

annotation. After deploying I don't see the property "sling.filter.scope = REQUEST" in the Felix console and the servlet is also not triggered.

Any idea why?
The OSGI-standard annotations do work:

```
@Component(service = Filter.class,
    property = {SLING_FILTER_SCOPE + "=" + FILTER_SCOPE_REQUEST)
```

Answer (score 4):

Very probably the version of the bndtool is too low (at least 4.0.0).

Depending, what you use

- bnd-maven-plugin 4.0.0, or
- maven-bundle-plugin 3.0.0

See https://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/servlets.html (some details on bndtools are in the video)

Comment: Great, upgrading to version 4.0.0 of the maven-bundle-plugin helped. Thanks also for the provided link